# Understanding infection rate of a complex network

Tags: theoretical-biology, infection, infectious-diseases

Suppose we have a complex network of people and  the spread of a disease is modelled as a branching process ([Diekmann et al. 1998](https://pdodds.w3.uvm.edu/teaching/courses/2009-08UVM-300/docs/others/everything/diekmann1998a.pdf))

The rate of infection of the complex network is:

$r = \tau(n-2)-g$

where $\tau$ is the infection rate of the disease through 1 person

$n$ is the # of people in the network

and $g$ is the effective # of people / sec.

What does $g$ mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try particularly hard to find it, but I was not able to find the equation you include in the paper. Potentially you might need to share the exact source of the equation. After going through this (rather superficially) I think that you are mixing up the *units* and the *definitions* of your terms.

I'm not an epi person so someone with better credentials should feel free to fill in / correct.

Regardless, the paper does provide some definitions for a quantity $g$ in equations 4.2-4.5, and provides some motivation in the following statement:

> We can use a branching process approximation to give a slightly more detailed description of the initial phase of an epidemic. Given ξ and given that the infective individual has k − 1 susceptible acquaintances, the probability that it will infect j acquaintances is equal to [Eqn 4.1, which is complicated]...

and then

> The probability π that this process goes extinct when we start it
> off with one individual can be found as the solution of the consistency condition

$\pi = g(\pi)$ (Eqn 4.3)

(see Eqn 4.4 as well)

$g$ is effectively a summation across that Eqn 4.1 with some extra decoration (including a term $z^{j}$ that they don't define very well but which I believe is the probability of not infecting any of $j$ individuals?), such that they then say

> The conditions g(0) > 0 and g′(1) > 1 guarantee that 0 < π < 1. Note that for the present definition of $p_j$

$ g′(1) = (k − 1)Q = R_0$.

Where $Q$ is the overall probability of transmission, $k$ is number of individuals in a group, and $R_0$ is the familiar minimum viable reproductive rate.

I'm not going to stare at these equations any longer, but suffice it to say that $g$ appears to be a description of the now-unsusceptible (previously infected + immunized) population- when one more person gets infected, there is one less person who is susceptible (under this model, anyways).